# Nuxtjs & Databases

Tags: javascript, database, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've been learning Nuxtjs (some previous coding knowledge but brand new to web dev) but I'm still pretty unclear as to how I should be storing data in a Nuxt project. I am working on a data collection/estimation tool for my window cleaning company and I'd like to store information like the customers name & address, and also relate that data to the pane count and subsequent quotes/quote revisions.

Is the Vuex store the appropriate place to be storing this kind of information? I'm especially conscious about the fact that this is technically considered "personal data" which Canadian law protects under PIPA/OIPC. I'm having a really hard time finding tutorials that connect a Nuxt project to Firebase Firestore or some kind of SQL database. I have, however, found several (terrible) tutorials on Udemy by people who can barely speak English who are connecting Nuxt & Laravel together, which should (I assume) build a working PHP/SQL framework for storing/retrieving data. My current tutorial by Academind on Nuxtjs is just diving into the Vuex store, so I'm also wondering if that's because most people use the Vuex store. I figured I'd get some expert input before continuing down the wrong path to try to get where I am going.

I'd love some deeper insight here. Any information you can provide would be a great help. If you have some great tutorials to point me to I'd be happy to check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the Vuex store the appropriate place to be storing this kind of information?

Definitely not. Vuex store definitely not for those sensitive information, and Vuex is state management pattern + library, so it's not database. Secure database is considered better practice. And another thing might need to be paid attention would be GDPR. You can start simple database such as Google Sheet as JSON/mySQL (for simple entries for SSR NUXT to render) until complex noSQL Databases (Firebase/Mongo etc.)

I would really advice go through Vue fundamentals (OpenClassroom is good course there too) before going any further into NuxtJS.

Comment: Looking back I would add that I was simply not educated on exactly how a full-stack application works. It would be worth mentioning the concept of a backend api or even something like Firebase Functions to handle jobs with API keys or auth information/tokens privately - in my case, when interacting with the database.